# Where is the error in this Sequelize query?

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

I've been using sequelize for a while now but this is the first time I've been encountering an error like this. Here's the code :

```
const results = await Article.findAll({
  where: {
    Sections: {
      [Op.any]: {
        contents: {
          ops: {
            [Op.any]: {
              insert: {
                [Op.like]: `%${searchString}%`
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
});
```

And here's an example of the data structure i'm querying :

```
    "Sections": [
      {
        "contents": {
          "ops": [
            {
              "insert": "Test text\n"
            }
          ]
        },
        "type": "text",
        "id": 3,
        "createdAt": "2023-04-08T08:43:53.227Z",
        "updatedAt": "2023-04-22T09:32:00.133Z",
        "sectionId": 4,
        "articleId": 4
      },
      {
        "contents": {
          "ops": [
            {
              "insert": "Test text\n"
            }
          ]
        },
        "type": "text",
        "id": 5,
        "createdAt": "2023-04-08T09:42:30.266Z",
        "updatedAt": "2023-04-22T09:32:00.137Z",
        "sectionId": 4,
        "articleId": 4
      }
    ],
```

I've tried shifting around some of the Ops, separating everything in different objects, however, I'm constantly getting the error : `Invalid value : {[Symbol(any)]: { contents: [Object] } }`

From my trials and errors, my understanding is it seems sequelize can't read past a certain level of nesting because the value it gets is `[Object]` rather than actual values ? But how could it be so ? And how should I solve this issue ?

EDIT :
I've dug a little deeper today and found out one big mistake from me. I was assuming that the Sections column was part of the article table, however, it was only a foreign key which I completely forgot it was, that's on me. That explains the problem I was facing in the first place.
Now here's the edited code :

```
Article.findAndCountAll({
      where: conditions,
      include: [{
        model: Section,
        as: 'Sections',
        where: {
          contents: {
            ops: {
              [Op.contains]: {
                insert: {
                  [Op.like]: `%${conditions.textSearch}%`
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }],
      limit: pagination.limit,
      offset: pagination.page * pagination.limit || 0,
      order: [["createdAt", "DESC"]],
    })
```

But hey, that doesn't resolve my issue either : I'm still getting `Error: Invalid value { insert: { [Symbol(like)]: '%test%' } }`

Here is the 'Sections' structure :

```
const structure = {
  contents: DataTypes.JSONB,
  type: DataTypes.STRING,
  id: {
    type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
    autoIncrement: true,
    primaryKey: true
  }
};
```

And the intialization :

```
  Article.hasMany(Section, { foreignKey: "sectionId" });
  Section.belongsTo(Article, { foreignKey: "articleId" });
```

EDIT 2:
Today's research saw me trying the literal way, which made me realize what I'm trying to do might even not be possible in Raw SQL.
Here's what it looked like :

```
SELECT count("Article"."id") AS "count" 
FROM "Articles" AS "Article" 
LEFT OUTER JOIN "Sections" AS "Sections" ON "Article"."id" = "Sections"."sectionId" 
// this is the crunchy bit, where I couldn't find a way to both 
//extract the array 
//and perform an ILIKE on the "insert" field. 
AND("Sections"."contents"#>{'ops'}) @> "{'insert': 'queryString'}" 

LEFT OUTER JOIN "Users" AS "User" ON "Article"."UserId" = "User"."id" 
LEFT OUTER JOIN "Images" AS "Images" ON "Article"."id" = "Images"."ArticleId"
```

Digging deep into Postgres doc, I'm pretty sure they don't provide the tools for such query.

Comment: What does the actual schema look like?

Comment: Sections : Array<JSONB>

Comment: @Pointy I've actually got ahead of myself by a huge margin lol, sorry... I've edited my post

Comment: Should a value for the conditions with `Op.any` be an array?

Comment: @Anatoly You're right, but I didn't do anything (`[Op.any]: [{insert: {...`). Also I switched to Op.contains which seems more appropriate for this case either.

Comment: Why do you need `Op.contains`? Shouldn't you skip it at all?

Comment: @Anatoly the "ops" field is an array of Objects which all contains at least the field "insert". In js, that query would look like `contents.ops.any(op => op.insert.includes(queryString))`